How to split logic into modules using Embedded HAL in Rust (no_std)?
I'm exploring the use of Rust in embedded systems and I've using ESP32 with esp-hal crate and friends.
To this end, I've setup an ESP32 with a microSD card reader and a PCM5102a audio DAC to play some WAV files (PCM). I've created a fairly simple logic mostly in main() to do the initialization of peripherals, buffering, and passing of data from the microSD card to the DAC, and it works pretty well. The audio playback is nice and smooth.
The thing is that now, I want to start separating things into logical unit blocks (and working my way out of the mess in main). For example, I would like to create a Dac struct to contain all the DAC initialization functions and internal buffering arrays.
For example, this is how I initialize the ESP32's I2S0 peripheral (in main):
let p = esp_hal::init(esp_hal::Config::default());
let io = Io::new(p.GPIO, p.IO_MUX);

let ws = io.pins.gpio5;
let dout = io.pins.gpio6;
let bclk = io.pins.gpio7;
let mclk = io.pins.gpio4;

let dma = Dma::new(p.DMA);
let (_, rx_descriptors, tx_buffer, tx_descriptors) = dma_buffers!(0, 48000);

let i2s = I2s::new(
  p.I2S0,
  Standard::Philips,
  DataFormat::Data16Channel16,
  44100.Hz(),
  dma.channel0.configure(false, DmaPriority::Priority0),
  rx_descriptors,
  tx_descriptors)
  .with_mclk(mclk);

let mut i2s_tx = i2s.i2s_tx
  .with_bclk(bclk)
  .with_ws(ws)
  .with_dout(dout)
  .build();

let mut transfer = i2s_tx.write_dma_circular(&tx_buffer).unwrap();

I can use transfer to write bytes that will be sent to the DAC using DMA.
Now, I want to move all this initialization code to a struct called Dac and pass pins that will be used to communicate with the DAC, the DMA peripheral that will be used for transfers to that particular Dac instance, sample rate, number of channels, bit depth, etc.
For example, I would love to do something like this:
let p = esp_hal::init(esp_hal::Config::default());
let io = Io::new(p.GPIO, p.IO_MUX);

let dac = Dac::new(
  p.DMA,          /* DMA Peripheral */
  p.I2S0,         /* I2S Peripheral */
  io.pins.gpio5,  /* WS Pin */
  io.pins.gpio6,  /* DOUT Pin */
  io.pins.gpio7,  /* BCLK Pin */
  io.pins.gpio4,  /* MCLK Pin */
  44100,          /* Sample rate */
  2,              /* Num of Channels */
  16              /* Bits per Sample */
);

dac.init();

/* Also at some point, I would like to change sample rate for example */
/* dac.reinit(48000, 2, 16); */

dac.write(&buffer); /* Write some bytes to the DAC */

The problem is that doing so has proved to be unmanageable due to Rust contraints of ownership. For example, I can't pass pins as variable io and p are moved and I can't use it anymore to initialize other peripherals in other modules. And so, many errors of the same type (unable to borrow some elements, etc.).
This of course may be mostly caused by my lack of knowledge and experience with Rust.
I've tinkering and managed to workaround almost all ownership problems, using traits and generic definitions in my struct but soon it is plagued by generic definitions, lifetimes, etc., and the code is really ugly IMHO.
Is there some guidance on how to effectively share embedded-hal (esp-hal) traits and references between different parts of the program and be able to use peripherals separatedly in different logical modules of the application?
Also, buffers and that sort of thing has proven difficult to encapsulate in a struct. In main, all buffer initialization and its use is right there, but as soon as I try to move to a struct for better encapsulation, I run into problems, with references, mutability and things not being static anymore.

It's not an answer. But from a brief look it seems like structs like Peripherals and Pins aren't supposed to be kept around. If you deconstruct them you can pass the ownership of the resulting fields to you modules.

Hey, thanks! What exactly do you mean by "deconstruct them"?

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html?highlight=destructure#destructuring-to-break-apart-values
